# Processing (iterate through) several (HDF5) files and several nodes in each HDF file

Tags: python, iteration, filenames, hdf5

How can I automatically process ascending file names and array names in Numpy:

I have a series of HDF5 files named:

```
20120101.hdf5, 20120102.hdf5, 20120103.hdf5, ..., 20120130.hdf5, 20120131.hdf5
```

each of the hdf5 file contains several arrays naming:

```
array1, array2, array3, ..., array24
```

I want to modify each of the arrays seperately and then create corresponding new hdf5 files. For example, using `20120101.hdf5`:

```
import numpy
import tables

file = openFile("20120101.hdf5","r")
b1 = file.root.array1
c1 = (b1<=1)
new20120101_array1 = creatArray('/','1',c1)
c2 = ((b1<=2) and (b>1))
new20120101_array1 = creatArray('/','2',c2)
.
.
.

c20 = ((b1<=20) and (b>19))
new20120101_array1 = creatArray('/','20',c20)
```

and repeat it for arrays 2-24. As a result, I want to have:

```
new20120101.hdf5 ---- new20120101_array1 ---- 1
                                              2
                                              ...
                                              20
                 ---- new20120101_array2 ---- 1
                                              ...
                                              20
                 ...
                 ---- new20120101_array24 --- 1
                                              ...
                                              20
new20120102.hdf5
....
new20120131.hdf5
```

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: How to do it automatically? Instead of changing names manually?

Comment: Your code is not properly written:
If you do `import tables`, then you have to write all the functions from this module as `tables.function`. If you write `file = openFile(...)` and `new = creatArray(...)` it wont work! To use the code as you wrote it you must call the module as `from tables import openFile, creatArray` or `from tables import *`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have several files in a directory, you can use the `os.listdir` function, which returns a list containing the names of the entries in the directory.

Example:

```
import os
import tables

direc = '/Users/cg/' # the working directory (where your files are stored)
dirs = os.listdir(direc)

for idir in dirs: # this will iterate over the files in your working directory

    if idir.endswith('.he5'): # only for HDF5 files...
        hdf5 = tables.openFile(os.path.join(direc,idir))

        #### DO WHAT YOU WANT WITH EACH FILE!

        hdf5.close()
```

The other part of your question is already answered in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10526636/how-to-batch-select-and-calculate-arrays-in-numpy), I guess (you can use the `walkNodes` function ).

Comment: In this example I am using the library [PyTables](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html) to deal with HDF5 files. There are other libraries that you can use.

Comment: and I will give you an advice...

When you want to know what exactly a function is doing and what it returns, type `help(function)`. For example, to find out what is `os.path.join` doing, you should write `help(os.path.join)` and you will get: *Join two or more pathname components, inserting "\" as needed. If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your answers and advices!