# How to batch select and calculate arrays in Numpy?

Tags: arrays, batch-file, numpy, iteration, hdf5

How to (1) batch select all arrays under a hdf5 file, then (2) apply calculations on those arrays and finally (3) batch create new arrays in another hdf5 file?

for example:

```
import numpy
import tables

file = openFile('file1',"r")

array1 = file.root.array1
array1_cal = (array1 <= 1)
newfile.createArray('/','array1_cal',array1_cal)

array2 = file.root.array2
array2_cal = (array2 <= 1)
newfile.createArray('/','array2_cal',array2_cal)
```

I have 100+ arrays under a single hdf5 file and several hdf5 files, how can I batch process them? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the structure of your HDF file? For example, are all the arrays hanging off the root?  Did you want that structure to be replicated in the new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [PyTables](http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/libref.html) you can use the `walkNodes` function to recursively iterate through nodes. Here is an example:

```
# Recursively print all the nodes hanging from '/detector'.
print "Nodes hanging from group '/detector':"
for node in h5file.walkNodes('/detector', classname='EArray'):
    data = node[:]
    // do some calculation 
    // store new array in second file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **h5py**, the Python interface to HDF5. **h5py** allows you to use HDF5 files, groups and datasets using traditional Python and NumPy metaphors.

see http://code.google.com/p/h5py/ and http://alfven.org/wp/hdf5-for-python/